# Comparing two tables and returning rows that do not exist based on multiple field comparisons

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a Table called **#ListTable**:

```
Item:
Apple
Bannana
Pea
Milk
Green
```

And Another Table **Food** similar to:

```
Date       Fruit       Vegetable      Dairy       Color
2/16/17    Apple       NULL           NULL        Green
2/16/17    NULL        Pea            NULL        Green
2/16/17    NULL        NULL           Milk        White
```

If the value in the list exists in the Food Table I want to return the record.

So I have something like:

```
DECLARE @Date = '2/16/17',
@InclusionFlag = 1

SELECT *
FROM Food F
INNER JOIN #ListTable LT1
ON F.Fruit = LT1.Item
WHERE Date = @Date

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM Food F
INNER JOIN #ListTable LT2
ON F.Color = LT1.Item
WHERE Date = @Date

...
```

Essentially returning a record if the item in the List corresponds to one of the fields I specify. I know there could be "duplicate" records like Apple being "Apple" and "Green" and I want that.

However, I also want to be able to toggle the Inclusion Flag to 0 and return items in ListTable that do not have a match with any fields in Food.

How would I return that list of securities that do not match? I know there are similar questions but I am having trouble figuring it out for the multiple field comparison case.

Thanks

Comment: Use a stored-procedure that handles the `InclusionFlag` with `IF ... ELSE...`. Then write the appropriate query for every column

Comment: right i understand that. i am just having trouble with the else part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`cross apply()`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)** to unpivot your data first, then use a `case` expression with `when exists()` in your `where` clause to return 0 or 1 when it exists and compare that to `@InclusionFlag`.

```
;with FoodItem as (
  select x.Item
  from food as f
  cross apply (values (Fruit),(Vegetable),(Dairy),(Color)) as x (Item)
  where x.Item is not null
    and f.Date = @Date
)

select 
    lt.Item
from ListTable as lt
where case when exists (
    select 1 
    from FoodItem fi 
    where lt.Item = fi.Item
  ) then 1 else 0 end = @InclusionFlag
```

Comment: can you alter so you return the rows from the Food table instead of the list when there is a match?

Comment: nvm dont worry... i got it

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, Food rows (may be repeating) matching #ListTable

```
SELECT F.*
FROM Food F
INNER JOIN #ListTable LT1
ON LT1.Item IN (F.Fruit, F.Vegetable, F.Dairy, F.Color)
WHERE Date = @Date
```

Comment: That's going to show `Green` twice for the single entry from `#ListTable`

Comment: @Serg I am testing yours now... in terms of returning "duplicate columns", If I have "Green" And "Apple" in my list, I should return that first row in my Food table twice in the results. does yours do that

Comment: @SqlZim SELECT DISTINCT F.*  .. to avoid doubles.

Comment: i want doubles so I will leave